# Java MouseListener - Event by enter and exit a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hi i have a problem with the MouseListener and the events.

When i have the following code then every Panel has his own Listener and when i enter or exit this Panel than the hover-effect works fine.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            final JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                p.setBackground( Background );
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                p.setBackground( Hover );
            }
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            });
            p.setOpaque( true );
            p.setBackground( Background );
            p.setPreferredSize( new java.awt.Dimension( 15, 15 ) );
            p.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Border ) );
            Pane.add(p);
        }
    }
```

But when i wrote a own class and implements the JPanel and the Listener in this new class then only the last panel is triggert. Where is the problem?

```
Main Class
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            final Pad p = new Pad();
            Pane.add(p.getContent());
     }
 }
 ...

public class Pad{  
private static  JPanel p; 
public Pad(Color Back, Color Hov, Color Bord,String name){
     ...
     p = new JPanel();
     p.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    p.setBackground( Background );
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    p.setBackground( Hover );
                }
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
                });
            p.setOpaque( true );
            p.setBackground( Background );
            p.setPreferredSize( new java.awt.Dimension( 15, 15 ) );
            p.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Border ) );
}
public static Container getContent(){
       return p;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your have a `static` reference to the `JPanel` `p`...this means, that the last `JPanel` assigned to `p` will be accessible to ALL instance of the `MouseListener`....

```
private static  JPanel p; 
public Pad(Color Back, Color Hov, Color Bord,String name){
     p = new JPanel();
```

Instead, try something more like...

```
private JPanel p; 
public Pad(Color Back, Color Hov, Color Bord,String name){
     p = new JPanel();
```

Or even

```
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    e.getComponent().setBackground( Background );
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    e.getComponent().setBackground( Hover );
}
```

But, I'd still get rid of the `static` reference.